# Can I travel to Mexico in a vehicle registered in someone else's name?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, borders, mexico, permits

I want to travel to Mexico in my Dad's truck, registered in his name. Can I get a vehicle permit to do so?

I have tried to call banjercito but they don’t answer.

Comment: How far into Mexico are you planning to travel?